# Speed up Postgresql query with multiple joins

Tags: postgresql, join, indexing, query-performance, explain

Please help me to optimize the following query:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT 
"subscriptions"."id" AS t0_r0,
"subscriptions"."created_at" AS t0_r3, 
"subscriptions"."updated_at" AS t0_r4, 
"subscriptions"."next_date" AS t0_r5, 
"subscriptions"."number_of_games" AS t0_r6, 
"subscriptions"."renewal_date" AS t0_r7, 
"subscriptions"."type" AS t0_r8, 
"subscriptions"."order_id" AS t0_r9,
"orders"."id" AS t1_r0, 
"orders"."customer_id" AS t1_r1, 
"orders"."created_at" AS t1_r2, 
"orders"."updated_at" AS t1_r3, 
"orders"."payment_id" AS t1_r4, 
"orders"."status" AS t1_r5,
"orders"."col13" AS t1_r13, 
"orders"."col14" AS t1_r14, 
"orders"."col15" AS t1_r15,
"orders"."active_subscription_id" AS t1_r21, 
"orders"."product_id" AS t1_r22 
FROM 
"subscriptions" 
INNER JOIN "orders" ON "orders"."id" = "subscriptions"."order_id" 
WHERE 
"subscriptions"."type" IN ('Const1') 
AND "orders"."status" = 'confirm' 
AND "orders"."product_id" IN (1, 95, 79, 22) 
AND ("subscriptions"."renewal_date" BETWEEN '2017-09-23' AND '2017-09-29') AND (orders.active_subscription_id = subscriptions.id) 
AND ("subscriptions"."number_of_games" >= 5) 
AND ("subscriptions"."id" NOT IN (
SELECT subscriptions.id 
FROM "subscriptions" 
INNER JOIN "orders" ON "orders"."id" = "subscriptions"."order_id" 
INNER JOIN "table1" ON "table1"."order_id" = "orders"."id" 
WHERE "subscriptions"."type" IN ('Const1') 
AND "orders"."status" = 'confirm' 
AND "orders"."product_id" IN (1, 95, 79, 22) 
AND "table1"."col1" IN ('1041', '1042') 
AND ("subscriptions"."renewal_date" BETWEEN '2017-09-23' AND '2017-09-29') 
AND (orders.active_subscription_id = subscriptions.id) 
AND ("subscriptions"."number_of_games" >= 5))
    ) ;
```

Initially there're b-tree indexes on:

```
CREATE INDEX index_table1_on_order_id ON table1 USING btree (order_id);
CREATE INDEX index_orders_on_active_subscription_id ON orders USING btree (active_subscription_id);
CREATE INDEX index_orders_on_status ON orders USING btree (status);
CREATE INDEX orders_payment_id_idx ON orders USING btree (payment_id);
CREATE INDEX index_subscriptions_on_order_id ON subscriptions USING btree (order_id);
```

All columns with name "id" are primary key.
Execution plan:

```
    Nested Loop  (cost=18699.70..38236.80 rows=1 width=466) (actual time=11185.634..11336.548 rows=3352 loops=1)
   ->  Seq Scan on subscriptions  (cost=18699.28..37754.22 rows=57 width=76) (actual time=11185.610..11309.520 rows=3356 loops=1)
         Filter: ((renewal_date >= '2017-09-23'::date) AND (renewal_date <= '2017-09-29'::date) AND (number_of_games >= 5) AND (NOT (hashed SubPlan 1)) AND ((type)::text = 'Const1'::text))
         Rows Removed by Filter: 522626
         SubPlan 1
           ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.85..18699.28 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=6743.644..11185.269 rows=31 loops=1)
                 ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.42..18697.21 rows=1 width=12) (actual time=0.150..1792.440 rows=3383 loops=1)
                       ->  Seq Scan on subscriptions subscriptions_1  (cost=0.00..17740.06 rows=114 width=8) (actual time=0.114..145.256 rows=3387 loops=1)
                             Filter: ((renewal_date >= '2017-09-23'::date) AND (renewal_date <= '2017-09-29'::date) AND (number_of_games >= 5) AND ((type)::text = 'Const1'::text))
                             Rows Removed by Filter: 522595
                       ->  Index Scan using index_orders_on_active_subscription_id on orders orders_1  (cost=0.42..8.39 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.471..0.484 rows=1 loops=3387)
                             Index Cond: (active_subscription_id = subscriptions_1.id)
                             Filter: (((status)::text = 'confirm'::text) AND (subscriptions_1.order_id = id) AND (product_id = ANY ('{1,95,79,22}'::integer[])))
                             Rows Removed by Filter: 0
                 ->  Index Scan using index_table1_on_order_id on table1  (cost=0.43..2.05 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=2.775..2.775 rows=0 loops=3383)
                       Index Cond: (order_id = orders_1.id)
                       Filter: ((col1)::text = ANY ('{1041,1042}'::text[]))
                       Rows Removed by Filter: 5
   ->  Index Scan using index_orders_on_active_subscription_id on orders  (cost=0.42..8.46 rows=1 width=390) (actual time=0.007..0.007 rows=1 loops=3356)
         Index Cond: (active_subscription_id = subscriptions.id)
         Filter: (((status)::text = 'confirm'::text) AND (subscriptions.order_id = id) AND (product_id = ANY ('{1,95,79,22}'::integer[])))
         Rows Removed by Filter: 0
 Planning time: 3.928 ms
 Execution time: 11337.023 ms
```

Creating the following index:

```
CREATE INDEX index_subscriptions_on_renewal_date ON subscriptions USING btree (renewal_date);
```

doesn't make things much better. Even rewriting the query doesn't improve the performance either:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
With subscriptions_1 as (
SELECT 
"subscriptions"."id" AS t0_r0, 
"subscriptions"."created_at" AS t0_r3, 
"subscriptions"."updated_at" AS t0_r4, 
"subscriptions"."next_date" AS t0_r5, 
"subscriptions"."number_of_games" AS t0_r6, 
"subscriptions"."renewal_date" AS t0_r7, 
"subscriptions"."type" AS t0_r8, 
"subscriptions"."order_id" AS t0_r9
FROM 
"subscriptions"
WHERE
"subscriptions"."type" IN ('Const1')
AND ("subscriptions"."renewal_date" >= '2017-09-23' AND "subscriptions"."renewal_date" <= '2017-09-29')
AND ("subscriptions"."number_of_games" >= 5)
ORDER BY "subscriptions"."id"
)
SELECT
Subscriptions_1.*,
"orders"."id" AS t1_r0, 
"orders"."customer_id" AS t1_r1, 
"orders"."created_at" AS t1_r2, 
"orders"."updated_at" AS t1_r3, 
"orders"."payment_id" AS t1_r4, 
"orders"."status" AS t1_r5, 
"orders"."col13" AS t1_r13, 
"orders"."col14" AS t1_r14, 
"orders"."col15" AS t1_r15, 
"orders"."active_subscription_id" AS t1_r21, 
"orders"."product_id" AS t1_r22
FROM
Subscriptions_1
INNER JOIN "orders" ON "orders"."id" = subscriptions_1.t0_r9 
WHERE
"orders"."status" = 'confirm' 
AND "orders"."product_id" IN (1,95,79,22)
AND (orders.active_subscription_id = subscriptions_1.t0_r0)
AND (subscriptions_1.t0_r0 NOT IN (SELECT subscriptions_1.t0_r0 FROM subscriptions_1 INNER JOIN "orders" ON "orders"."id" = subscriptions_1.t0_r9 INNER JOIN "table1" ON "table1"."order_id" = "orders"."id" WHERE "orders"."status" = 'confirm' AND "orders"."product_id" IN (1,95,79,22) AND "table1"."col1" IN ('1041', '1042') AND (orders.active_subscription_id = subscriptions_1.t0_r0))
) ;
```

Comment: `Creating the following index:`Did you run ANALYZE after creating the index? Also: probably a composite index, containing the date field would be better. (the date *seems* to be part of a candidate key) And the `IN(...)` subquery could be rewritten to  an`EXISTS()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The plan is so bad because PostgreSQL underestimates the number of result rows (1 instead of the actual 3383 in the join between `subscriptions` and `orders`).

That causes PostgreSQL to pick a nested loop join for the join with `table1`, which is where 9 of your 11 seconds are spent.

There are several approaches:

1. Run `ANALYZE`, perhaps with increased `default_statistics_target`, on all tables affected. Perhaps fresh statistics will lead to a better estimate.
2. If that doesn't help, create an index `ON table1(order_id, col1::text)`, which will speed up the nested loop join as much as possible.
3. The brutal way: set `enable_nestloop` to `off` for this one query.

Comment: Yes please please please let us know what worked, struggling with a very similar query!